# How should I do a URL re-direct so that the user cannot use the 'Back' button

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I would like to redirect users away from a page such that they cannot use the 'Back' button to return to that page. In addition, I would like to make them stay on that page, unless:

1. They type something else in the address bar and navigate away, or
2. They close down the tab/browser.

This probably means that after the redirect clicking on the 'Back' button does nothing or the 'Back' button is simply disabled.

What is the right way to do this across the modern browsers (e.g. IE9+, Chrome, FireFox, etc)?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: A new window that closes it's parent/caller. But regardless of the method, you can't prevent the user from backtracking using the browser's history.

Comment: one does not simply disable the back button

Comment: @RichardEv, for flow-control reason, more specifically, I want users to concentrate on the page that they are redirected to, such that the only way they can leave the page is by one of the two ways listed above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way would be to use AJAX, you can also use no-cache attributes which tell the browser to store no pages in cache, which mean there won't be any back button functionality as there would be no history.

Anyways, there are ways of course,

1. Open all links in new tab, window.
2. Use ajax.
3. Use no-cache attributes.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior woud be very annoying however if you want to do it then use hash values
like

```
<script>
window.onhashchange=function(){
window.location.hash='a';
}
window.onload=function(){
window.location.hash='a';
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

the best idea i have is to use ajax to load new content in the window :

$('body').load('/newpage.html')

I don't think there is a way to make the browser disable the back button... also, they can also navigate using bookmarks.

Another thing you can do is open a new window that doesn't have the address bar. If you ok with opening a new window, this might be the best option

Answer (score 1):

You can imitate disabling back button on your page. Here are three ways you can achieve this. Take a look [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/buttons/article.php/3478911/Disabling-the-Back-Button.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function goNewWin() {
window.open("backbuttonnewpage.html",'TheNewpop','toolbar=1,
location=1,directories=1,status=1,menubar=1,
scrollbars=1,resizable=1');
self.close()
}
</SCRIPT>
<A HREF="javascript:goNewWin()">Click to go to a new page</A>
```